# Convexity of Frobenius norm of inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am working on a problem where I'm trying to characterize if a loss function is convex or not. The loss function is of the following form:

$$f(\boldsymbol{W}) = ||\boldsymbol{S} - (\boldsymbol{I} - \boldsymbol{W}^{\top})^{-1} (\boldsymbol{I} - \boldsymbol{W}^{\top})^{-\top}||_F^2,$$
where $\boldsymbol{S}$ is a known symmetric matrix and $\boldsymbol{I}$ is the identity matrix.

I'm not exactly sure how I should proceed in this case! Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Some info on $\boldsymbol{W}$, $\boldsymbol{W}$ corresponds to the weighted adjacency matrix of a directed acyclic graph. This results in the diagonal entries of $\boldsymbol{W}$ being zero.

Comment: Did you do some numerical experiment? Also, is there any condition on $W$?

Comment: I haven't done any numerical simulations yet, I wanted to see if there is direct way to analyze the convexity here. $\boldsymbol{W}$ corresponds to the adjacency matrix of a directed acyclic graph. This enforces some constraints on it, but one direct implication is that the diagonal entries are 0.

Comment: Perhaps you should add something about W.

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly not convex, if $W$ varies over $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \backslash \{I\}$ with the Euclidean metric. If $W_1:=\epsilon I$ and $W_2:=(2+\epsilon) I$, then $f\left(\frac{W_1+W_2}{2}\right)$ approaches $\infty$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: Would that change if the diagonal entries of $\boldsymbol{W}$ is 0? Then it cannot be of the form $\varepsilon\boldsymbol{I}$.

Comment: Restricting the diagonal wouldn't. The basic problem is that it diverges to $+\infty$ at a point in the middle of the domain. If your edge weights are nonnegative then $\mathbf{W}$ is also nonnegative, and acyclicity means that if the $i,j$th element is nonzero then the $j,i$th element is zero, and possibly some other conditions. I suspect that isn't quite enough to make the function convex, but it helps. I think the real problem is that your search domain isn't convex - if the $i,j$th element of $W_3$ and the $j,i$th element of $W_4$ are both nonzero, then $\frac{W_3+W_4}{2}$ is not acyclic.